Private Ethereum Network using PoA for Production
I want to setup a "production" private Ethereum network using PoA as the consensus algorithm. However the latest documentation stated that Geth only supports the Ethereum PoS consensus mechanism. So I can no longer use Proof of Authority for my private network?
In the same doc, there is a step to spin a test private net using kurtosis. Is there any resource or article i can refer to setup my private network using PoS without using kurtosis?

I saw a lot of your questions on this stack and I'm in a pretty similar situation. I don't want to use extra tooling that I'm unfamiliar with to set up a development private network, then possibly push it to production.
There's a pretty helpful guide over at Prysm (you know, the consensus client) that sets up a pure POS Geth private network which seems to be... adequate.
https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/advanced/proof-of-stake-devnet

Thank you Dimitris Sfounis

@0x75aaa if you've found the answer useful, feel free to mark it as "completed"!
